# While loop (in a background process) reading from file descriptor does not exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'll explain my problem statement first. I have a command1 which generates data on both stderr and stdout, the stdout is piped to command2, while the stderr should go to a background process which continuously calls an API.

Dummy example of the same:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e;

metric_background_process () {
    # This while loop waits till there is a line to read
    while read -u 3 -r line; do
        echo $line;
    done;
    
    # This never prints !!!
    echo "Done"
}

tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
mkfifo "$tmp_dir/f1"

# Allocate a file descriptor to the named pipe
# to allow read and write from it.
exec 3<> "$tmp_dir/f1"

metric_background_process <&3 &
pid=$!


# Main commands (stdout is being piped to stderr as a dummy case)
cat ./assets/random_file 1>&3

exec 3<&-

wait $pid
```

The input file contains: 1 through 9, with 9 being the last line.

Observed Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

The shell waits after printing `8`, `9` is not printed, and the program does not stop by itself.

No matter what I try, the `while` loop does not exit. Maybe I'm missing something simple, any help or further questions for clarification would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent shell is opening the fifo for read/write (`<>`). The subshell (`&`) inherits the FD so it's also opening the fifo for read/write. When the parent closes the FD the subshell is still opening the fifo for writing so the write side is never closed and so the read side (`read -u 3`) cannot get `EOF`.

To make it a bit simpler —

The script:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
metric_background_process () {
    local fifo=$1

    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done < $fifo
    
    echo "Done"
}

tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
fifo="$tmp_dir/f1"
mkfifo "$tmp_dir/f1"

metric_background_process $fifo &
pid=$!

exec 3> $fifo

for i in {1..5}; do
    echo i=$i >&3
done

exec 3>&-

wait $pid
```

Result:

```
$ bash foo.sh
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
i=5
Done
```

Comment: While I tried your solution and it definitely works, could you tell me where I was wrong, cause I do not understand the root cause of this?

Comment: i added some explanation after the answer was accepted. please take a look.